# Getting the class of the element being clicked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jQuery snippet that collapses the responsive `navbar` (in mobile mode) when a menu item is clicked.

```
$('.navbar-fixed-top').click('li', function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

However, I also have a couple of menu items with drop-down sub-menus and they have the Bootstrap class `.dropdown` assigned to them. I want the above function to exempt these dropdown menu items.
To that end, I would like to retrieve the class of the item being clicked in order to make a decision on whether to collapse the navbar.

I tried this but it didn't output anything.

```
$('.navbar-fixed-top').click('li', function() {
    console.log($(this).class);
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

I also tried this with similar results.

```
$('.navbar-fixed-top').click('li', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.class);
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

What else can I try? Right now, my navbar collapses when the dropdown menu item is tapped on a mobile device even before the user has a chance to see the sub-items which is what I am trying to remedy.

In case anyone wants to take a look, here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about')}"><a onClick="pagetop()" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/blog')}"><a onClick="pagetop()" href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a onClick="pagetop()" href="#">PREMIUM</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">RESOURCES<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick="centerAlignModal()" data-target="#contact" data-toggle="modal">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: are u trying to get the `id` for the class?

Comment: are you looking for `hasClass`?

Comment: Class. Just corrected the snippet.

Comment: @naveen: All I need is to somehow reference the <li> that was clicked and then retrieve its class.

Comment: `event.target` (from your last snippet) will give you the thing that was clicked. Just remove the `li` event.

Comment: Cannot remove the <li> because it's that individual li that was clicked that I am trying to retrieve.

Comment: ```$('.navbar-fixed-top li').click(function(event) {
console.log(event.target.class);
$('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: If I move the `li` to the first parentheses, it would prevent the collapse from triggering when the user clicks on any non-li area of the navbar. That's not what I want. I want the collapse (this function) to trigger when the navbar is clicked anywhere except the li with a certain class (`.dropdown`).

Comment: You can retrieve the class of menu was clicked like this $(this).attr('class')

Comment: Where is `.navbar-fixed-top` in your html? Just wondering if naming is right.

Comment: `.navbar-fixed-top` is the element that contains the HTML snippet I posted along with a whole bunch of other stuff such as the title logo, hamburger menu (for mobile devices), search box, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, you can do:

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

which is equal to [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) in plain JS:

```
event.target.className;
```

---

Since `target` references the anchor, you need the class of its parent (which is the li element). Try clicking the first two items here (added dummy-classes for them):

```js
$('.nav').click('li', function(e) {
  alert(e.target.parentElement.className);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li class="aboutClass" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about')}"><a href="#about">ABOUT &lt;--- click me</a>
  </li>
  <li class="blogClass" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/blog')}"><a href="#blog">BLOG &lt;--- click me</a>
  </li>
  <li><a onClick="pagetop()" href="#">PREMIUM</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">RESOURCES<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick="centerAlignModal()" data-target="#contact" data-toggle="modal">CONTACT</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Already tried it and it didn't work because `this` is referencing the entire navbar instead of the li being clicked within the navbar. I need to reference that specific li that triggered the event.

Comment: Let me write you a snippet.

Comment: See it now, added a little explanation.